# Как узнать кнопку из формы, которая запустила PHP скрипт?

Tags: php, html, mysql

Здравствуйте, имеется более 100 записей (которые, естественно, выведены автоматом через php). В каждой записи есть своя форма вида:

```
<form action="#" method="post">
                <div>
                    <input type="text" class="in_name" id="edit" value="" placeholder="Введите измененный текст..." tabindex="1" />
                </div>
                <div>
                    <input type="submit" id="btn" name="'.$id.'" class="action-button" value="Изменить" />
                </div>
            </form>
```

Как можно задетектить какая именно была нажата кнопка и передать ее значение вместе с Input текстом в PHP скрипт?

Код вида:

```
if( isset( $_POST['Какая-то кнопка'] ) ){
Бла; бла; бла;
}
```

как понимаете, трудновато вставлять 100 раз для каждой записи...

Comment: А у Вас 100 записей выводятся с одинаковым id у кнопок submit?

Comment: Нет, вывод записей через while происходит. 
ID постоянно изменяется.

Comment: Я имею в виду вот это: id="btn"

Comment: А, этот id не изменяется.

Comment: А Вы знаете, что id должен быть уникальным?

Comment: Хорошо, ладно. Понял ошибку. Но этим как-то можно разрешить мой вопрос?

Comment: Нет, я просто указал Вам на грубую ошибку в разметке. Что касается вопроса, то можно, например, с помощью js добавлять к name какие-нибудь уникальные значения, которые  дадут понять, какая именно кнопка нажата (если я правильно понимаю, что Вам требуется)

Comment: берете js и отправляете только одно единственное значение поле на сервер, + его идентификатор. поля не именуйте, а динамически прикрепите к форме. либо чисто аяксом отправьте

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас в форме только одна кнопка. В тех случая когда в форме больше одной кнопки и необходимо различать нажатия, то к каждой кнопке добавляют атрибут name, в котором указывают название кнопки.
Здесь, я так понимаю, вы хотите получать идентификатор записи, к которой был добавлен введенный текст. Это можно удобно сделать через скрытое поле:

```
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?= $id ?>">
```

На серверной стороне это значение вы сможете использовать через глобальный массив пост:

```
$_POST['id']
```

Comment: Согласен с автором выше, у вас только одна кнопка и в зависимости от тэга <form> name этой кнопки будет доступен в глобальном массиве $_POST или $_GET

Comment: У него в форме указан method="post", так что $_POST

Answer (score 1):

Кнопки отправки формы могут быть полноценным полем с полноценным значением:

```
<button type="submit" name="item_id" value="345">Изменить запись 345</button>
<button type="submit" name="item_id" value="678">Изменить запись 678</button>
```

Потом в PHP достаёте `$_POST['item_id']` и всё. При этом неважно, одна большая форма у вас или много маленьких. Впрочем, для кучки маленьких форм можно сделать и hidden-поле, как предлагают в соседнем ответе.

*<sup>P.S. id="edit" и id="btn" уберите, повторение id в html-коде запрещено.</sup>*

*<sup>P.P.S. Атрибут action из формы лучше тоже убрать. Его отсутствие автоматически означает, что POST-запрос нужно отправить на текущий адрес.</sup>*